# Run Five SQL query from a script

Tags: python, sql, perl, hive

I have `Five SQLquery` that I need to run, either `Sequentially` means one by one or `Independently`. As currently what I am doing is that, I need to run all those `Five SQL query` sequentially in one `Putty session` or I can open five `Putty Session` and  enter one query each in those five Putty Sessions. So its very tedious and I need to run it manually. So I was thinking to automate the process.

Is there any way using some sort of scripts like Perl Script or Python script from which I can run all my Five queries either Sequentially or Independently?

Queries in my case are little bit complex and long but considering the above scenario I am taking the below five queries as an example- And these Five queries are not related to each other. And also these five SQL queries I am running using Hive.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1;
SELECT * FROM Table2;
SELECT * FROM Table3;
SELECT * FROM Table4;
SELECT * FROM Table5;
```

So My Question is how can I do that in any script language? Also I am not specific to any script, Just wanted to know which is better approach in my case. Any code snippets fulfilling my requirement will be appreciated.

I am working with HiveQL and HiveQL syntax is same as SQL Sytnax.

P.S. I am new to all the scripting languages.

Comment: you didnt specify what flavor of sql.... but yes you can in any scripting language

Comment: I am working with HiveQL and HiveQL syntax is same as SQL Sytnax.

Comment: How do you open the HiveQL session to run the queries?

Comment: I go to Putty and then I type the Hostname and username and password and then Type Hive at the command prompt. And then I can type my SQL queries.

Comment: In the Hive prompt, can you try entering @queries.sql, where queries.sql file has the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this and this is a pretty basic example.  The upshot is that in Perl you control the sequence of execution by simply placing the "execute" commands in the order desired.  I'm assuming you're familiar with Perl DBI and how to connect to your dbase.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use DBI; 
use strict; 

my $dbh = DBI->connect($your_connect_string) || die qq{Could not connect to $dbase\n};     
my $sql_1 = qq{ select * from table1}; 
my $sql_2 = qq{ select * from table2};
my $sql_3 = qq{ select * from table3};

my $sth_1 = $dbh->prepare($sql_1); 
my $sth_2 = $dbh->prepare($sql_2);
my $sth_3 = $dbh->prepare($sql_3);

$sth_1->execute();
$sth_2->execute();
$sth_3->execute();

while (my $hashref_1 = $sth_1->selectrow_hashref()) { 
...do something
} 

while (my $hashref_2 = $sth_2->selectrow_hashref()) { 
...do something
} 

while (my $hashref_3 = $sth_3->selectrow_hashref()) { 
...do something
} 

$sth_1->finish(); 
$sth_2->finish(); 
$sth_3->finish(); 

$dbh->disconnect(); 

exit;
```